# What can be done with a phone that has an encrypted bootloader

Tags: encryption, bootloader

I am trying to get a rooted android phone set up for reverse engineering purposes. I tried to root two separate phones (SM-G925A and a Google Pixel 2) but they both turned out to have locked (meaning, encrypted by the carrier) bootloaders.

Is there really no way to get around this without finding an exploit? I have tried everything short of taking the phone apart and flashing the ROM in (whatever device you use to flash a ROM chip.) Would that even work? I can't even find a single example of someone doing this for any model of phone on the internet.

Comment: A bootloader does not encrypt or decrypt anything. Hence a bootloader is never encrypted. I assume you are referring to the digital signature that can be checked by the bootloader but again neither the bootloader nor the checked software is encrypted.

Comment: @Robert indeed bootloader lock state is encrypted, but that's different topic

Comment: @alecxs Are you really sure you mean encryption and not cryptographically tamper protected?  Do you have any reference for the encryption in bootloader?

Comment: @alecxs If the bootloader is OEM locked, you can't unlock the bootloader without using an exploit. For both the pixel 2 (verizon model) and SM-G925A, there are currently no known exploits. I'm 100% sure about this.

Comment: @Robert I'm not completely sure how it works honestly, you could be right about that

Comment: @Robert the latter one. gklsodascb right, verizon is a different story, kindly include that info in your question

Comment: some older unlock stories, just linking https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unlock-bootloader-on-verizon-pixel-2-confirmed.3730076

Comment: regarding samsung try to re-brand SM-G925F with modded Odin https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/patched-odin-3-13-1.3762572 or find combination rom according to your bootloader version https://samsungfirmware.net/samsung-galaxy-s6-edge-sm-g925a-combination-firmware