# Bootloader wont unlock on Google Pixel 2 (G011A)

Tags: rooting, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I'm trying to root my Google Pixel 2 but I can't get the bootloader unlocked.

The phone is a renewed and unlocked international version, model number G011A.

From the bootloader screen, and connected to the computer, this is the result from the following commands:

```
fastboot flashing unlock
```

> FAILED (remote: 'Flashing Unlock is not allowed')
> fastboot: error: Command failed

```
fastboot flashing unlock_critical
```

> FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
> fastboot: error: Command failed

It is communicating with the device:

```
fastboot devices
```

> {{device serial number}}         fastboot

and unlocking the bootloader seems to be enabled on the phone

```
fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability
```

> (bootloader) get_unlock_ability: 1
> OKAY [ 0.000s]
> Finished. Total Time: 0.000s

I've tried using a Windows 10 laptop and an Ubuntu laptop, both with the same results. I read that USB ports/cables can be problematic, so I've tried all the USB ports on both laptops using two different cables with the same result.

On the phone itself, developer options are enabled, USB debugging is enabled, and OEM unlocking is enabled.  Curiously, OEM unlocking becomes grayed out and disabled after enough failed attempts, but I've been fixing this with a factory reset.

The Android version is 11, build RP1A.201005.004A1

What am I missing here? Why wont this bootloader unlock? Thanks!

Comment: [Note: the '`flashing unlock'` command is only available with fastboot version 23.0.1 or later. The latest available version of fastboot can be downloaded from SDK Platform Tools](https://developers.google.com/android/images) - update fastboot version and try // Also `fastboot flashing unlock_critical`  **should not** be used on your device, it's only for 2XL

Comment: it seems that more and more OEMs follow Huawei philosophy, some people reported for Samsung and Oppo devices not unlockable after 7+ days

Comment: @beeshyams I should have said, my fastboot version is 30.0.5-6877874. If `fastboot flashing unlock_critical` is not the correct command, what is? The XDA tutorial says they use the same command. https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-unlock-bootloader-and-root-the-google-pixel-2-and-pixel-2-xl/

Comment: @alecxs I'm not sure what you're saying. Its an unlocked Google Pixel 2, so it should be able to have the bootloader unlocked. Its not as though Google is not allowing flashing of its own Android devices.

Comment: not for verizon, sprint, etc https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232947/

Comment: *"It should also be noted that many if not most Pixel phones that are advertised for sale as 'unlocked' phones are in fact simply 'carrier unlocked' phones"* https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/53018654

Comment: @alecxs I don't think that applies here, since `get_unlock_ability` command says its its able to be unlocked, and the OEM unlock in the developer settings is also enabled.

Comment: that description claims only [OPD3.170816.012](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:UC8jfchLC3QJ:https://www.ebay.com/itm/Very-rare-Google-Pixel-2-Brand-New-Unlocked-Bootloader-Unlockable-/224300369443) is unlockable (and very rare). However, this [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/latest-december-update-shows-security-update-as-october.4207129) is contradictory

Answer (score 2):

I just wish I could find someone who figured out a work around.  From what I have read Google has intentionally blocked the change of bootloader lock.
https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/14920605/google-refurbished-pixel-2-is-always-defective-bootloader-unlock?hl=en

Comment: please note link-only answers are discouraged. As you are the author of that link please copy+paste OP here in addition to your link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/245892)