# Is Android 10 unrootable?

Tags: samsung, rooting, root-access

I'm trying to root my device but after doing so much research, I've found that the rooting apps either don't work because it was made for an older version of android, it found that it's not rootable at all from the info given (such as android version and model number), or the download button just doesn't work. I've tried apps like One Click Root, Framaroot, Root Master, and Kingo Root. So I came here to look for an answer. Is it possible to root my phone in anyway, no matter the method? Below is some device info:

```
Model number: Samsung Galaxy S9 (SM-G960U)
Android Version: 10.0
```

If any more info is needed, please let me know in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Check https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-extreme-syndicate-g960u-u1.4041815/ Maybe you have already read it.

Comment: the question is more about bootloader unlocking than about rooting [1](https://www.xda-developers.com/fix-missing-oem-unlock-samsung-galaxy-s9-samsung-galaxy-s8-samsung-galaxy-note-8), [2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bounty-fix-for-persistent-rmm-state-lock-after-7-days.3886716). one-click-routing is dead since android 6+ [3](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706). bootloader unlocking dies nowadays with huawei google samsung oppo, others will follow [4](https://www.xda-developers.com/safetynet-hardware-attestation-hide-root-magisk), [5](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233310)

Comment: Did you check if Magisk is supported on the S9?

Comment: Android is almost always rootable, devices are not. As alecxs mentioned, it depends on if your bootloader is unlockable or not. Locked bootloaders (and an other OEM-specific protection mechanisms) aren't Android, technically. Getting root without unlocking the bootloader is just a bonus, not an expected behavior: [Is there a way to root an Android phone without unlocking the bootloader?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218886/218526)

Comment: You have a full guide to root Galaxy S9 at https://www.androidinfotech.com/root-samsung-galaxy-s9-plus-exynos-sm-g965-android-10/
but that is full on unlocking bootloader and disabling knox which will have consequences in terms of warranty or apps that need payments

Comment: there is also root exploit for locked bootloader without tripping knox, see first comment Reddy Lutonadio (although not for U8)

Comment: Is it possible to unroot the phone with SuperSu? If that won't work with S9, how about with a file manager?

Comment: You mean `unroot` as losing root privileges @MatthewSchell? With FilManger I doubt.  But you can always do whole procedure of bootloader locking again, to go back to original state minus knox security, unless you  can hack it as @alecks suggested

Comment: Yeah I mean to completely reverse all changes I made to my phone to get root in the first place, I know rooting a device poses a security threat so I want to do what I need to do quick and then unroot it again. If keeping the bootloader unlocked also poses a security threat, I want to undo that too

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio is the Extreme Syndicate safe to use?

Comment: @Denis did you say I can't get knox security back even after unrooting?

Comment: I don't own a S9, so I can't say if it is safe or not. You need to search, read what others have done and tried, then decide whether you will root or not. Make sure you know the steps and what went right or wrong based on the experience of those who tried before you.

Comment: @MatthewSchell as far as I'm aware in Android 9 or 10 there is not possible to restore knox.  As mentioned above there is a way for 8 so you would have to downgrade