# How to root my tecno camonX CA7

Tags: applications, rooting, root-access, processes

How to root camon X (CA7) or application for root access. How can i get root access?

Whenever i try it root it, it keeps saying no root access

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, Ekwegbalu! Just in case you wonder about the downvotes (not from me btw) – your question lacks several details. As the device is not exactly well-known, a link to its specs would help. And especially what you've tried to root it – as it makes no sense if you get the very same stuff as recommendations which you know that failed, unless you used those tools wrongly that is.

Answer (score 0):

Dump `boot.img` with [SP Flash Tool](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices),
patch with [Magisk](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info),
Unlock [bootloader](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233310/bootloader-wont-unlock-on-google-pixel-2-g011a),
flash [vbmeta](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image) disabled, and
flash `boot`