# Pixel 5 OEM unlock disabled or greyed out?

Tags: google-pixel

Working on installing a new OS for a friend on their Pixel 5 they just bought.
This isn't a carrier phone.

When I go to developer settings the OEM option is greyed out.
It suggests to connect to the internet or contact the carrier.
I have the phone hooked up to wifi, so I do not believe that is an option.
I have yet to put a SIM card in the phone.

I was wondering what is a work around to get the OEM disabled option available for a Pixel 5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootloader wont unlock on Google Pixel 2 (G011A)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233310/bootloader-wont-unlock-on-google-pixel-2-g011a)

Comment: you can install new OS by *"Apply update from SD Card"*

Comment: @alecxs Little hesitant to do that. All the suggested instructions I am following to install grapheneOS successfully do not suggest that.

Comment: of course only google official [ota.zip](https://developers.google.com/android/ota#redfin) can installed from stock recovery/on locked bootloader