# How to ensure a device will allow me to OEM unlock it, so that I can install a custom ROM to it when I have the IMEI?

Tags: bootloader-lock

I'm about to buy an Android phone from someone in my area. He already told me the IMEI. How can I ensure that I can unlock the bootloader ("OEM Unlock") prior buying the phone?

I've heard that I might have to wait 7 days until I can unlock the OEM, so I need to know the phone will be unlocked eventually, to avoid wasting my money. I have no use for the phone if the bootloader stays locked.

Comment: Only a handful of phones can be bootloader unlocked these days... What specific model of phone? The IMEI really doesn't tell you anything in this case.

Comment: @acejavelin Pixel 6a. I've seen it locked with grayed out OEM unlock option right after purchase, but I think it has just a 7 day lock. I'm not sure.

Comment: Kind of related: [Bootloader wont unlock on Google Pixel 2 (G011A)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233310/44325) where the answer mentioned refurbished Google Pixel 2 are intentionally bootloader locked. So, in the end, I guess there's no way to ensure until you get the device and try to unlock it.

Comment: if it is Samsung or Google phone, don't buy it

Comment: The 6a had a bug when launched that OEM unlock was grayed out. The OTA update fixed it, or the Android 13 update. Mine was grayed out as well, but as soon as I got the first OTA it was fine.

Comment: @acejavelin we tested the June 2022 update without success. That's all the phone wanted to receive.

Comment: This wouldn't by chance be a Verizon model? In the Verizon model the bootloader is never unlockable. What is the model of the device is Settings - About Phone - Android Version, what is the full build number?

Comment: @acejavelin It was a device from a warehouse in Germany, no carrier was involved. I'm aware of the critical lock nature of Verizon devices, shouldn't be the case here, however the device we had was locked and thus promptly returned. Later, I figured out that there might be just a 7 day lock, as some people on XDA asked about the 7 day OEM lock period and how to circumvent it. There are tricks you can pull off (like disabling NTP sync, changing the date to 8 days into the future and rebooting), but I'm not aware Google addressed such bypasses in recent history.

Comment: @acejavelin Maybe it's indeed the Android 13 update or the 7 day wait period that would fix it, but both solutions aren't appealing as of now. We will wait for used devices to ensure the OEM unlock is not grayed out before purchase.

Comment: @alecxs What else gives 5y+ software updates (incl. firmware updates) and the opportunity to install a privacy focused ROM such as GrapheneOS? Other good devices have 2-3y software updates. DivestOS would be a fine choice to bypass this with successful bootloader re-lock for good security, but that won't lengthen firmware update support time. Sustainability phones offer up to 5y as well (FairPhone, PinePhone), but the hardware is just bulky and weak. Ultimately, only bloated stock ROMs or GrapheneOS offer a verified bootloader, afaik. I rather choose the latter if I pick a new phone.

Comment: (to me) it's pointless if bootloader isn't unlockable - which was the question here